# Obtaining the NSOutlineView "special group" font

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In a Finder window on the left, you can see various "special groups" like FAVORITES, DEVICES, etc. written with a special font.

You see a very similar (if not the same) font used for "special groups" in NSOutlineView.

How can I get at this exact font? I want to use it for drawing text in my custom views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite sure it's Lucida Grande Bold:

[image]

Here's a [somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654420/where-can-i-find-apples-standard-source-list-sidebar-icons) question.